# CSS/HTML causing paragraph to display wrong

Tags: html, css

On my site [cur-mudg-eon.com](http://cur-mudg-eon.com) I'm having a problem having a paragraph display properly.  If you visit the homepage you'll notice that "Paragraph #1" is located to the right of H2 "[ker-muhj-uhn]" and I want it to be to align left underneath the H1 title "Cur-mudg-eon".

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to figure out my error.

Comment: You need to clear your floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your headline's css contains "float: left", so it will "float" to the left of any content. You have to clear the floats. After the `</h2>`, insert

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

This means that no floating element is allowed to the left or to the right of this div. After the div, your paragraph will display normally.

As was suggested in a comment, you could also add the `style="clear:both"` to the paragraph, that would be:

```
<h2> ... headline ... </h2>
<p style="clear: both"> ... </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

"br" (break)tag after the H2 should help

```
<H2>text </h2><br/>Paragraph 1
```

Answer (score 0):

add a break tag "/br" after "/h2"

it should come down then

Answer (score 0):

Give your `p` a `clear: both;`, that should do the trick.